# Scala Lift - Save uploaded files to server directory

Tags: file, scala, lift

I'm currently storing images within the webapp folder of my Lift project, which I know will cause problems in future.

```
val path = "src/main/webapp/files/"
```

And the code I'm using to save it:

```
case Full(file) => 

    val holder = new File(path, "test.txt")
    val output = new FileOutputStream(holder)               

    try { 

        output.write(file) 

    } finally { 

        output.close() 

    }

}
```

What I'm trying to do is save the to the server root in an easily manageable folder called files, so SERVER_ROOT/files outside of the project folder.

Firstly how would I access the path to the root of the server so I can save them there?

Secondly how would I serve these files from my app, so I can display them on a page?

Thanks in advance, any help much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to store file to exact place on filesystem according to absolute path. I have written this code and it works, so maybe it helps you:

```
def storeFile (file : FileParamHolder): Box[File] = 
  {
    getBaseApplicationPath match
        {
            case Full(appBasePath) =>
            {
                var uploadDir = new File(appBasePath + "RELATIVE PATH TO YOUR UPLOAD DIR")
                val uploadingFile = new File(uploadDir, file.fileName)

                println("upload file to: " + uploadingFile.getAbsolutePath)

                var output = new FileOutputStream(uploadingFile)
                try
                { 
                    output.write(file.file)
                }
                catch 
                { 
                    case e => println(e) 
                }
                finally
                { 
                    output.close
                    output = null
                }

                Full(uploadingFile)
            }
            case _ => Empty
        }
  }
```

and this is my getBaseApplicationPath function which finds out absolute path of local machine (server or your devel PC):

```
def getBaseApplicationPath: Box[String] = 
    {
        LiftRules.context match
        {
            case context: HTTPServletContext => 
            {
                var baseApp: String = context.ctx.getRealPath("/")

                if(!baseApp.endsWith(File.separator))
                    baseApp = baseApp + File.separator

                Full(baseApp)
            }
            case _ => Empty
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, how would I use your getApplicationPath function with my existing code? For example I want to save the files to "C:/files/". Thanks again